# creating single array from an array having object inside it

Tags: javascript

I have a data which looks like this

```
console.log(this.x)  //[Array(963), Array(964), Array(954)]
console.log(typeof this.x[0]) //object
```

Now, I want to merge all these 3 arrays inside the object to form a single array.

**[Question:]** How can I do it?

A side note, `console.log(this.x)` could also contain 5 or 6 arrays.

**[Update:]** I only want value pairs and not the keys from array.

This is how the data looks if I open of the array

```
console.log(this.x[0]) //

 Array(963)
  >[0 … 99]

0: 23244
1: 2324610.25
2: 2035083.25
3: 1807027.25
4: 1931790
5: 1507934.25
6: 1547601
7: 1443744.5
8: 1417907.5
9: 1124118
10: 1110016.625
```

And similarly for `console.log(this.x[1])`

```
1: Array(964)
>[0 … 99]
0: 45877.59766
1: 0
2: 0
3: 50099.19141
4: 0
5: 0
```

I want it to be single array having just the values
Say something like this

```
[23244, 2324610.25, 2035083.25 ... , 1124118, 1110016.625, 45877.59766, 0, 0, 50099.19141, 0, 0]
```

Comment: you want to merge all arrays from `this.x` and put in object?

Comment: create a single array instead of having three arrays

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your desired input -> output. can you show, how x looks like?

Comment: Give a clear example for the initial data and how do you expect them to become

Comment: @KuchBhi - Answers below does exactly the same as required. Can you highlight the discrepancy observed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

> The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

```js
var x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
x = x.flat();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: @Mamum Thanks for answering, Updated the question, can you please go through it again?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this. I have listed a few below.

```js
var a = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]];
console.log(a.flat());
console.log([].concat(...a));
console.log(a.reduce((c,d) => c.concat(d), []));
```

References, [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Updated the question, can you please go through it again?

Answer (score 2):

The operation you are looking fore is referred to as "flattening". There is an [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method which does exactly this.

```
const x = [[1,2,3],[3,4]]
console.log(x.flat())
```

Comment: Updated the question, can you please go through it again

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const arr = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,2]];

const flat = arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);

console.log(flat);
```

Comment: Updated the question, can you please go through it again